# При установке времени РАНЬШЕ системного служба срабатывает мгновенно

Tags: android, android-alarm-manager, службы

В данный момент разрабатываю будильник на Android. Вроде бы всё работает, однако при установке в TimePicker времени, которое по сути РАНЬШЕ системного( например системное время 15:00, если при этом в TimePicker выставить 13:00, то будильник, т.е служба срабатывает мгновенно, а не на следующий день как нужно.

Сама же службa, AlarmService:

```
package android.projects.alarmapp;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
import android.util.Log;

public class AlarmService extends IntentService {
private static final String TAG = "AlarmService";
MediaPlayer mPlayer;
private static Context mContext;

public AlarmService() {
    super(TAG);
}

public static void setServiceAlarm(Context context,long time){
    Intent i = newIntent(context);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context,0,i,0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) 
context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,time,pi);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
    boolean isOn = AlarmPreferences.isAlarmOn(mContext);

    Intent i = MainActivity.newIntent(this);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i,0);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setTicker("УВЕДОМЛЕНИЕ")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.picture)
            .setContentTitle("УВЕДОМЛЕНИЕ")
            .setContentText("Какой-то текст")
            .setContentIntent(pi)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();

    NotificationManagerCompat manager = 
    NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    manager.notify(0,notification);
    while(isOn){
        play();
        isOn = AlarmPreferences.isAlarmOn(mContext);
    }

    stop();
    Log.i(TAG," БУДИЛЬНИК ОТКЛЮЧЕН!");


}

private void play(){
    if (mPlayer == null){
        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mContext,R.raw.alarm);
        mPlayer.setLooping(true);
    }
    mPlayer.start();
}

private void stop(){
    if (mPlayer != null){
        mPlayer.release();
        mPlayer = null;
    }
}



public static Intent newIntent(Context context){
    return new Intent(context,AlarmService.class);
}
}
```

Фрагмент:

```
package android.projects.alarmapp;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.projects.alarmapp.databinding.FragmentLayoutBinding;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class AlarmFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable 
ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    FragmentLayoutBinding binding = 
FragmentLayoutBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false);
    final TimePicker timePicker = binding.timePicker;

    binding.startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlarmPreferences.setAlarmOn(getActivity(),true);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,timePicker.getCurrentHour());
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,timePicker.getCurrentMinute());

            AlarmPreferences.setTime(getActivity(), 
    calendar.getTimeInMillis());


  AlarmService.setServiceAlarm(getActivity(),calendar.getTimeInMillis());
            Log.i("TAG"," БУДИЛЬНИК ЗАВЕДЕН");

        }
    });

    binding.stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlarmPreferences.setAlarmOn(getActivity(),false);
        }
    });



    return binding.getRoot();
    }
 }
```

AlarmPreferences:

```
package android.projects.alarmapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

public class AlarmPreferences {
private static final String ALARM_ON = "isAlarmOn";
private static final String TIME = "time";


public static void setAlarmOn(Context context,boolean isOn){
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
            .edit()
            .putBoolean(ALARM_ON,isOn)
            .apply();
}

public static boolean isAlarmOn(Context context){
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
            .getBoolean(ALARM_ON,false);
}

public static void setTime(Context context, long time){
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
            .edit()
            .putLong(TIME,time)
            .apply();
}

public static long getTime(Context context){
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
            .getLong(TIME,0);
}
}
```

Какие есть варианты решения данного неприятного бага?

Comment: почему баг?) надо просто довести дело до конца и добавить ко времени ещё и дату

Comment: Ясно, я просто думал, что если время раньше системного установить, то AlarmManager без всяких проблем "будет ждать" пока не придет его час.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как и указали в комментариях, нужно добавить следующее:

```
if (calendar.before(Calendar.getInstance)){
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
}
```

где calendar - ваш календарь.